# Django Websocket: Messages are all sent after loop is finished

Tags: python, django, websocket, python-asyncio, channel

I am trying to create a application, where i start the game with a countdown. For that I have a loop counting down. The problem is when i am awaiting my send loop, all messsages are sent after the loop is finished. When i am putting the function in a task it is sending instant but thats not what i want because I need to wait for the function to call another after.

Thats the the countdown function

```
async def init_starting(self):
    if not self.lobby.status == "waiting":
        print("Already Started")
        return False
    else:
        print("Starting Countdown")

        self.lobby.status = 'starting'
        await self.save_lobby()

        await self.send_status_message_with_status(status='starting', data={'has_started': self.lobby.has_started,
                                                                            'host': self.host.username,
                                                                            'players': self.players,
                                                                            'lobby_code': self.lobby_code,
                                                                            'countdown': 3})

        countdown = 3
        while countdown >= 0: # here are the messages not sent instant but after the loop is finished (with my current approach they are sent instant but i cant await it
            countdown_data = {
                'countdown': countdown
            }
            await self.send_status_message_with_status(status='starting', data=countdown_data)

            countdown -= 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        self.lobby.status = 'started'
        await self.save_lobby()
        await self.send_status_message_with_status(status='started', data={
            'message': "Test"
        })

        return True
```

Here i am currently starting the task

```
if "command" in text_data_json:
        command = text_data_json['command']

        match command:
            case 'start':
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                start_task1 = loop.create_task(self.init_starting()) # here i would like to await the task but when i do it they are not sent instant


            case _:
                print("Code not found")
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Have you double checked it's not just finishing super fast?- ex) by making all those sleeps 45 seconds or longer

Comment: oh should have said that, it waits until the seconds have past

Comment: How do you know tho?- are you also storing a timestamp in the message? I'm just saying **4 Seconds** is a small time slot to validate if they're sending when they're supposed to or not

Comment: You need to provide some context for the creation of start_task1.  Your question doesn't make much sense, because inserting a line `await start_task1` immediately after its creation does NOT affect the execution of start_task1.  But it does prevent the code from proceeding past `await start_task1` until start_task1 is finished, so it affects the program as a whole.  If nothing else, insert a print statement into the while countdown loop to verify when the messages are really sent.

Comment: Sorry should have added that I tested it with print and the print was sent instant. The timestamp in insomnia says the messages were all send at once, so no time between.